# Pyspark union of two dataframes

Tags: pyspark

I want to do the union of two pyspark dataframe. They have same columns but sequence of columns are different

I tried this

```
joined_df = A_df.unionAll(B_DF)
```

But result is based on column sequence and intermixing the results. IS there a way to do do the union based on columns name and not based on the order of columns. Thanks in advance

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just reorder columns in B so that it has the same column order as in A before `union`:

```
A_df.unionAll(B_df.select(*A_df.columns))
```