# PySpark : Merge two dataframes

Tags: dataframe, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

I have two dataframes, DF1 and DF2 and they have same column names

Lets say the DF1 is of the following format,

| Item Id | item | model | price |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | item 1 | 22 | 100 |
| 2 | item 2 | 33 | 300 |
| 3 | item 3 | 44 | 400 |
| 4 | item 4 | 55 | 500 |

DF2 contains following format

| Item Id | item | model | price |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | item 1 | 222 | 1000 |
| 1 | item 1 | 2222 | 10000 |
| 2 | item 2 | 333 | 3000 |
| 3 | item 3 | 444 | 4000 |
| 4 | item 4 | 555 | 5000 |

I need to combine the two dataframes such that the  result should be like:

| Item Id | item | model | price |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | item 1 | 22 | 100 |
| 1 | item 1 | 222 | 1000 |
| 1 | item 1 | 2222 | 10000 |
| 2 | item 2 | 33 | 300 |
| 2 | item 2 | 333 | 3000 |
| 3 | item 3 | 44 | 400 |
| 3 | item 3 | 444 | 4000 |
| 4 | item 4 | 55 | 500 |
| 4 | item 4 | 555 | 5000 |

I need to use only pyspark not pandas. Thanks for help.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Pyspark union of two dataframes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63549174/pyspark-union-of-two-dataframes)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may use a union here

```py
df1.union(df2)
```

or more specific

```py
df1.select("Item Id","item","model","price").union(df2.select("Item Id","item","model","price"))
```

optionally you may order your results

```py
df1.union(df2).orderBy("Item Id","item","model","price")
```

Let me know if this works for you.

Comment: works very fine. thank you for response